# How to change the "Alternative switch to next source"

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10, gnome-shell, system-settings

I have been using Ubuntu 17.10 for a while and is working great. But today after the update, I have a new shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, as an alternative Switch to the next input source. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is a common modifier in Intellij so a lot of shortcuts doesn't work any more.

I tried to change the shortcut but it is not listed in the shortcuts window.

Is there a file where I can change it (the alternative)?

Here is the screenshot of the option

[image]

Comment: For latecomers, this is also an issue in 18.04 for people upgrading from 17.10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1762952

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Finally I found the option. I had to install Tweaks and go to

**Keyboard and mouse > Additional layout options > switching to another layout**

The strange thing is that there is that the default shortcut <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> was not selected in that window, only the alternative shortcut.

Comment: Tweaks, mentioned by Alejandro Vera is the "Gnome Tweaks" application (could be found in "Software" or just from Activities search input)

Comment: Now it is called Tweaks https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-tweak-tool/commit/?id=05600c3af48c70925a2faf5663036f7eef62bff8

Comment: I had this short cut working until it suddenly stopped. The way to restore it as a short cut was to uncheck the check box, close Tweaks, open Tweaks again and select the check box again.

Comment: Language change: I set it up as described, it does work; but the language locale indication at the right corner of the monitor top panel bar ("en") does not change! Versions: Ubuntu 22.04.2, GNOME Tweaks 42.beta, GNOME Shell 42.5 (ubuntu mode)

Answer (score 4):

In my answer I assume that you use Gnome 3.x.

You can use *Tweaks*, but you can also write the value directly, for example, changing from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> can be done by the following command in terminal:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options ['grp:ctrl_shift_toggle','grp_led:scroll']
```

Comment: The [answer from avtomaton](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063750/250300) works all right, but don’t forget double braces: `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp:alt_shift_toggle','grp_led:scroll']"`

Answer (score 3):

To disable the option of alternative switch to the next source type in terminal:

```
xkbopts="/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options"
dconf read $xkbopts
dconf write $xkbopts "['']"
```

This worked for me. No reboot is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 18.04:
Alternative switch to next source
Can Changed or Disabled only with "Tweak Tool":

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
$ gnome-tweaks
```

and then 
**Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Switching to another layout**